# Clicked on Textbox it should select the radiobutton in c#

Tags: c#, radio-button

I have a Radiobuttonlist. In items i was adding Specify your own value with One textbox. I f i clicked on that text-box radio-button should select b y default.

```
 <td style="text-align:left" class="contract_value_bg" width="50%">
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblDocumentstType" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rblDocumentstType_SelectedIndexChanged" RepeatColumns="1">

                 </asp:RadioButtonList> 
             <asp:TextBox ID="txtRFP" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txtRFP_TextChanged" MaxLength="120"  />
            </td>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRLdA.png)

Comment: You want to set focus on the textbox if "specify your own value" was clicked in the RadioButtonList? Or you want to select that item in the `RadioButtonList` if the user clicked into the `TextBox`?

Answer (score 0):

You want to set focus on the textbox if "specify your own value" was clicked in the RadioButtonList? Or you want to select that item in the `RadioButtonList` if the user clicked into the `TextBox`?

This is for the former case:

```
protected void rblDocumentstType_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadioButtonList rblDocumentstType = (RadioButtonList) sender;
    if(rblDocumentstType.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {
        txtRFP.Focus();
    }
}
```

If you want to select the second `RadioButtonList` item if the `TextBox` got focus you should do that at client-side by handling the `onfocus` event with javascript (or jQuery):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtRFP" runat="server" onfocus="selectSpecifyYourOwn()"  AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txtRFP_TextChanged" MaxLength="120"  />

function selectSpecifyYourOwn() {
    var rbID = '<%=rblDocumentstType.ClientID %>';
    var rb = document.getElementById(rbID);
    var items = rb.getElementsByTagName("input");
    items[1].checked = true;      
}
```

Comment: I want to select that item in the RadioButtonList if the user clicked into the TextBox

Comment: @Elina: then the best would be to handle that on clientside, use the javascript `onfocus` event of the textbox

Comment: @Elina: have a look